# Threads are not doing their job when there is a print instruction

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to parallelize a simple job in python:

```
import threading


def function(dictionary):
    if threading.currentThread().name == "Thread 1":
        print("thread 1...")
        for i in sorted(dictionary)[0: int(len(dictionary) / 2)]:
            dictionary[i] = sum(dictionary[i])

    if threading.currentThread().name == "Thread 2":
        print("thread 2...")
        for i in sorted(dictionary)[int(len(dictionary) / 2):]:
            dictionary[i] = sum(dictionary[i])


dictionary = {}
dictionary["k1"] = [1, 1]
dictionary["k2"] = [1, 1, 1]
dictionary["k3"] = [1, 1, 1, 1]
dictionary["k4"] = [1]
dictionary["k5"] = [1, 1, 1]
dictionary["k6"] = [1, 1]
dictionary["k7"] = [1, 1, 1]
dictionary["k8"] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]



t1 = threading.Thread(name="Thread 1", target=function, args=(dictionary,))
t2 = threading.Thread(name="Thread 2", target=function, args=(dictionary,))

t1.start()
t2.start()

print(dictionary)
```

But, the output is:

```
thread 1...
thread 2...
{'k1': 2, 'k2': 3, 'k3': 4, 'k4': 1, 'k5': [1, 1, 1], 'k6': [1, 1], 'k7': [1, 1, 1], 'k8': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
```

and should be...

```
{'k1': 2, 'k2': 3, 'k3': 4, 'k4': 1, 'k5': 3, 'k6': 2, 'k7': 3, 'k8': 5}
```

And this only works when the print instruction is not in the code. Why is this happening?

Comment: FYI you can use `x // y` for integer division, instead of `int(x / y)`

Comment: You're not waiting for the threads to finish, so you're printing the dictionary that has been partially updated by the threads.

Comment: Ok, but why is the program working when I quit the print instruction?

Comment: Because the threads finish more quickly when they don't have to print something first.

Comment: @Chariot It isn't working, for precisely the reason Barmar explained. It happens to do what you happened to really want it to do. But that is *not* the definition of working in my book.